# Data not bound to model when manipulating table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a model containing a list and I'm using Razor to display the list items onscreen in a standard html table. A user can edit some parts of these items and save them, or they can add extra lines to the table.

For example, a master record may have 2 child records, the user can edit the 2nd record, then add a 3rd, then save and all the data is bound to the model as expected and is saved back to the database. **This all works fine**

The issue occurs when the user tries to delete a child record which is **not** the last record in the list. I'm using the following code to delete a child record, where ctrl is a delete icon which appears in each row.

```
deleteExtraLine: function (ctrl) {

    //get the table to which the ctrl belongs
    var table = $(ctrl).closest("table");

    //remove the row from the table
    $(ctrl).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

The issue I'm having is all rows after the one which was removed from the table are no longer bound to the model on the postback when saving.

ie. there are 5 rows, row 3 is deleted, but 4 and 5 are also deleted as they are missing from the model.

Is there some way of removing a row from the table which isn't going to affect the model in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I worked it out not long after I posted this.

The numbering of the name attribute needed to be contiguous so as soon as there was a gap it lost everything subsequent to that. So I had to write a function to make sure the number on the name attribute was in sequence

```
updateRowIndex: function(rows, index) {

    //index will start at the first row to be updated
    $(rows).each(function() {

        //get all the inputs and set the appropriate attribute values (this doesn't select the hidden ones but they don't matter anyway)
        var inputs = $(this).find("input");
        $(inputs).each(function () {
            //change the value for id
            var oldId = $(this).attr("id");
            var newId = oldId.replace(/\[[0-9]?[0-9]\]/ig, "[" + index + "]");        //eg replace all occurrences of [2] with [1];
            $(this).attr("id", newId);

            //change the value for the name attribute
            var oldName = $(this).attr("name");
            var newName = oldName.replace(/\[[0-9]?[0-9]\]/ig, "[" + index + "]");        //eg replace all occurrences of [2] with [1];
            $(this).attr("name", newName);
        });

        index++;
    });
}
```